# Dynamically pass table name to a query db2

Tags: db2

I need to do COUNT from table, which name is build dynamically and store the value

Tried two approaches, unsuccessful:

```
SET COUNT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BUILD_FUNCTION_NAME(a,b))


SET NAME  = BUILD_FUNCTION_NAME(a,b)
SET COUNT = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NAME)
```

Comment: You need to use dynamic-SQL, that is: make a variable to contain the SQL-statement at run time, then use either PREPARE + EXECUTE on that statement, or more convenient EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE.   Lots of examples in the documentation.

Comment: I see in documentation that both PREPARE + EXECUTE and  EXECUTE_IMMEDIATE are to be used for non-SELECT statement only

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_executeimmediate.html

Comment: That's for execute-immediate. Look at Prepare followed by execute.

Answer (score 1):

If it's DB2 for LUW, then try this:

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION GET_COUNT(P_TABNAME VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS BIGINT
BEGIN
  DECLARE V_RC BIGINT;
  PREPARE S1 FROM 'SET ? = (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM '||P_TABNAME||')';
  EXECUTE S1 INTO V_RC;
  RETURN V_RC;
END@

VALUES GET_COUNT('SYSCAT.TABLES')@
VALUES GET_COUNT('SYSCAT.COLUMNS')@
VALUES GET_COUNT('(SELECT 1 FROM SYSCAT.TABLES WHERE TABSCHEMA LIKE ''SYS%'')')@
```

You can pass even an arbitrary `SELECT` statement into such a function as a parameter.